# SQL Server: Making this rank for efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query to pull a customer's most recent purchase. I tried to use a subselect for performance reasons, but I ran into a wall and kept getting back ALL the customers' orders. I just need the most recent for each individual customer.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT od.*, ord.OrderName, ord.OrderDate, RowN = 
Row_Number() 
OVER (PARTITION BY ord.CustomerOrderGUID ORDER BY ord.OrderDate DESC)
FROM #OrderData od
JOIN CV3Orders ord ON ord.CustomerOrderGUID = od.CustomerOrderGUID
WHERE ord.ProductName = 'Product 10') rnk
WHERE rnk.RowN = 1
```

Comment: Can you show us your sample data and expected result?

Comment: I'm going to guess `CustomerOrderguid` isn't the same as a customerId, but rather an OrderId. Do you have a customerid column to `partition by` instead of the `CustomerOrderguid` ?

Comment: My data is made up of customers ordering a specific product. Customers have purchased the same product multiple times, so I'm trying to find the most efficient way of isolating the most recent purchase and displaying just the most recent purchase (Along with the other information from the row). For example, if I have a customer who purchased 3 bags of coffee in the past. I want to display the most recent purchase of coffee. The query I submitted works perfectly, but it takes quite awhile to run. I'm seeing if I can do the same thing with a subselect to shorten the execution time.

Comment: @sqlzim The CustomerOrderGUID is a key that allows me to join the Order table to the Customer table. It's the only thing I can join on that will work. I'm just trying to see if the query I submitted can be written into a subselect to increase performance (reduce execution time). I did write a subselect that partly worked: I did a SELECT TOP (1) on the OrderName and ordered by the OrderDate DESC, but it didn't isolate the the most recent order, it just ordered the all individual customer's orders from most recent to least recent and I only want the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

`CustomerOrderGuid` would seem to represent every *order* not every *customer*.  So, you need to partition by the correct column.  I might guess:

```
SELECT co.*
FROM (SELECT od.*, ord.OrderName, ord.OrderDate,
             Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ord.CustomerGUID ORDER BY ord.OrderDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM #OrderData od JOIN
           CV3Orders ord
           ON ord.CustomerOrderGUID = od.CustomerOrderGUID
      WHERE ord.ProductName = 'Product 10'
     ) co
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```